How does one define boundary conditions in electrostatics problems?
I am struggling to find a consistent method to approach electrostatics boundary condition problems. To motivate discussion, refer to Example 3.8, Problem 3.21, and Problem 4.24 from Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics (4th edition). The book can be found here.
In Example 3.8, we are told to use the symmetry of induced charges on the conductor. This conveniently defines the XY-plane as equipotential, so we may as well call it potential zero. Then, we can define some outer surface at $r >> R$. This can be arbitrarily large so the contribution of the sphere approaches zero. Hence, the potential change (with respect to XY-plane) is simply $V = -E_0z$. This creates two boundary conditions, and we can solve.
In Problem 3.21, we put a net charge on the conductor, which must be distributed uniformly to keep the sphere as an equipotential. One can easily solve this by superimposing with Example 3.8, but I am interested in understanding how the boundary conditions change. Without thinking, one might say that the sphere is still an equipotential so call it $V=0$. Far away the sphere does not matter, so the outer boundary condition is again $V = -E_0z$. But this is clearly wrong because these are the same boundary conditions as Example 3.8!
I resolved this by going back to the definition of $V$: it must be with respect to a reference point. I defined $V=0$ as a point far on the XY-plane. $V(boundary)$ can be identified by evaluating $-\int E \cdot dl$ when going from the reference point to the boundary. In Example 3.8, the induced charges create an electric field that points tangentially to $dl$ and therefore create no potential change. Similarly, the external field is perpendicular to $dl$ and creates no potential change. This justifies $V(sphere) = 0$. In Problem 3.21, the uniform charge acts like a point charge at the origin (Gauss's Law). Hence, $V(sphere)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_oR}$. In both cases, the outer boundary condition remains the same, because for sufficiently large $r$ the potential change from the reference is dominated by $-E_0z$.
This approach satisfied me, but I am struggling to apply it to Problem 4.24. We learn in section 4.4.2 that bound/surface charges allow us to use boundary conditions to solve problems in dielectrics. I can hand-wavily justify that since the external field is only in the $\hat{z}$ direction, any induced charges in the dielectric/conductor must only be in the $\hat{z}$ direction, and hence $V=0$ at the inner conductor sphere (of radius $a$) because like Example 3.8, the E-field is tangential to $dl$. Doing this and accounting for dielectric boundary conditions leads to a solvable problem.
I am wondering if there is an easier way to tackle these problems besides trying to think of the induced charges and using that to rationalize potential values at boundaries. Any correct approach must find a way to relate the "inner" and "outer" boundary potentials, and doing so seems to require thinking about induced charges, which at least for me then seems to require hand-wavy reasoning.

It would be clearer if you explained where this sphere is positioned and how this $R$ you introduce is defined and what you mean by "the conductor" (or link to an online version of the book you refer to).

@JosBergervoet Edited to include a link to the book. The diagram in Example 3.8 should help.

For example 3.8 we all seem to agree (Griffith's book included) that this can be solved by the boundary conditions you wrote down.
Then for problem 3.21, you propose to use the superimposing example 3.8 with (presumably) a charged sphere in an otherwise field-free region. This latter case has the potential on the sphere nonzero (it would be $V_{\text{sph}}=Q/C,$ if $C$ is the capacitance of the sphere). Superimposing that with example 3.8 would also require to add up the boundary conditions, so your step to "say the sphere is still an equipotential, so call it $V=0$" is not allowed. You know it will be nonzero, and by the superimposed problems, you know what value it has to be. It seems that you just didn't pay enough attention to one of the two problems you superimpose...
Then problem 4.24: your assumption that induced charges "must only be in the $\hat z$ direction" seems incorrect. The fact that $V=0$ on the sphere seems OK again ($V$ on a conductor must be constant, and we are not superimposing any other solution yet, so symmetry in the $xy$ plane gives $0$). But then the only approach I know is:

Just try combining the allowed potential shapes: $V=\alpha\ z/r^3+\beta\ z$ in some linear combination inside the dielectric, and in another one $V=\alpha'\ z/r^3+\beta'\ z$ outside the dielectric.
Fix the coefficients by the boundary conditions at the sphere, the dielectric outer surface, and far away.

This of course is a bit of an arbitrary "guess" approach to begin with, and also the boundary condition at the outer dielectric surface is a bit clumsy.
For the latter, we have to look at surface charges or at normal and tangential components of the $E$-field, and in any case, some fractions containing the relative dielectric constant $\varepsilon_r$ will come in. So I do not think that we can simply find two superimposed solutions that will solve it.

Regarding Problem 3.21, when I said "say the sphere is still an equipotential, so call it =0", I was trying to show how it's easy to get carried away with calling the sphere $V=0$ and the outer boundary $V=-E_0z$. This happens to work in Problem 4.24, but the point of including Problem 3.21 is to force a more rigorous strategy in defining boundary conditions.
And yes, my assumption on induced charges in 4.24 is not well stated. I meant they are symmetric and opposite in sign around XY-plane. It seems you are saying symmetry insists on this being the case, could you elaborate? Thanks.

Whenever there is positive charge (or potential) above the $xy$ plane there must be negative charge (or potential) at the mirror point below that plane. But the symmetry  is even stronger: all scalar quantities must have angular dependence $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle. For instance the charges on the sphere's surface in Griffith's Fig. 3.24. In problem 4.24 we will have two concentric charge distributions like that, one on the sphere and one on the outer dielectric surface. In that way there would be only two constants to determine to solve it!

Intuitively I agree that a positive charge above $xy$ plane should be mirrored with a negative charge below, I just have a hard time proving this must be the case. Do you know of a proof? Perhaps a way to solve this is to rely on intuition and assume this is the case, after which we can write the boundary conditions and solve. We know this solution satisfies the problem conditions, after which we can use a uniqueness theorem to know this is the only solution.

The stronger symmetry condition (that everything must have angle dependence $\cos\theta$) requires proof by group theory of the rotation group, it is not suitable for a quick intuitive explanation (although it can be proven intuitively with a little effort!). The weaker condition, that everything gets a minus-sign by reflection, is usually explained by saying that $xy$ is a "virtual ground plane". If you would cut the system in half, put a real conductive ground plane below the top half, you get the same solution. But that's not a real proof, it's just re-phrasing the assumption...

A better proof would be: 1) First assume that there is a solution (not necessarily symmetric in $xy$ plane). 2) mirroring this in the $xy$ plane and also giving it a minus sign will be a solution too. 3) This 2nd solution also matches the right boundary conditions far away. 4) So if we take the average of the two solutions it will still satisfy the boundary conditions far away. 5) This averaged solution clearly does have mirror-symmetry and is zero in the $xy$ plane. 6) Since the solution is unique our averaged solution is the right one. 7) So our starting solution already was the same.

I see, I agree this is a cleaner proof because my approach forced acceptance of symmetry to begin with whereas yours simply assumes a solution exists and shows it must be XY-symmetric. Anyways, it seems that when faced with these types of problems, some rationalization on induced charges is necessary. Symmetry arguments (like the one you explained) can make it possible to properly define the boundary potentials without being too explicit about the induced charge distribution. Would you agree?
